# Lead in & Lead to, what's the difference?

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, difference, phrases

So, as the title says, what's the difference between **"lead in"** and **"lead to"**, as can be seen in this example taken from the novel *The Name of The Rose*:

> "Thus it happened that we turned westward... almost following the line of mountains that from Pisa **leads in** the direction of the pilgrim's way **to** Santiago..."

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are linking the words incorrectly. The line of mountains leads _in a certain direction_. The pilgrims' way leads _to Santiago._

Answer (score 1):

This use of "lead" is followed by a direction/path, which could be a variety of prepositional phrases:

- All roads lead **to Rome**.
- All roads lead **from Rome**.
- All roads lead **in that direction**.
- All roads lead **over the hills**.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Name of the Rose by Umberto Eco was translated by a great translator. It is old fashioned on purpose.

- In modern English, the from Pisa would be move: almost following the line of mountains that leads from Pisa in the direction of the pilgrim's way to Santiago.

**|in the direction of the pilgrim's way] is one phrase inserted between lead and to. X leads to Y.**

One thing **leads to** another.

So, there is lead from Pisa [even though from Pisa precedes lead]....to
**And an interspersed phrase: in the direction of the pilgrim's way**

There is no lead in and lead to. There is lead to + in the direction of the pilgrim's way.

Comment: The road from Albany leads in the direction of New York, but veers west before it arrives.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, but that is not "lead in". It's leads |in the direction of New York| where "leads" and "in the direction of" belong to two separate bits of the sentence. That's exactly my point.

Answer (score -1):

"lead in" almost always comes before "the direction of" and it implies a future-tense state, as in

> This road will lead in the direction of-

**Note**: the proper past tense version of "Lead" is "Led"

"Led to" implies a consequence of action, such as

> "Robbing that bank led to my time in prison"

"Lead to" can't really be used properly in a sentence, however there are some examples: I can pull for it's use in other ways, such as;

> Alright, I will [lead him to] the exit.

"Lead" in that context implies a future state, just as "Lead In" does.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Lead to" can't really be used properly in a sentence*? Consider "All roads lead to Rome."

Comment: "Lead to" can be used as: "*Overspending will lead to bankruptcy*" (results in) or "*This premise leads to a clear conclusion*" (deduction, reasoning) or "*We hollowed his lead to the edge of the dessert*",  (direction)